# Symfony OAuth2 Bundle used as multi-tenant

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, symfony4

I have started using https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle so I can implement AzureAD authentication per company. (I'm using this https://github.com/TheNetworg/oauth2-azure as the provider).

I would like to use the oauth2-client-bundle for a multitenant application (in Symfony 4.4) with multiple Azure apps but, I have two issues:

First of all, How can I get the credentials and options from the database (through a Service or even through a controller class) directly in the yaml config file?

```
knpu_oauth2_client:
    clients:
        azure_1:
            type: azure
            client_id: 'x'
            redirect_route: 'edit_company'
            redirect_params: { id: '1' }
            client_secret: 'x'
```

And secondly, how can I dynamically add new entries to this container?
For example `azure_2`.

Is this possible? Am I missing something very important here?